# Получение нескольких таблиц из БД и создание новой таблицы

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Как с помощью (если это вообще возможно) одного адаптера данных получить из БД несколько таблиц в `ADO.NET автономный`.

В подключенном уровне можно написать в объекте команд через точку с запятой *sql-запрос*, например, такой:

```
select * from [db];select * from [db1]
```

и в итоге я получу содержимое двух таблиц.

Как нечто подобное сделать в автономном уровне, чтобы в один `DataSet` попало несколько таблиц, так как вариант с точкой с запятой тут не работает?

Возможно ли в автономном уровне создать БД на уровне кода, без использования *sql-команд*?

Таким образом, например, создаю объект `DataTable`, даю схему БД через добавление в массив `DataColumns` ну и заполняю `DataRow`, а потом это все отправить в датасет, чтобы сгенерировалась таблица. Или так не бывает ?

Comment: Заметил, что вы несколько раз употребили это словосочетание. Что такое "ADO.NET автономный"?

Comment: Ну, это уровень доступа по Троелсену. Автономный один раз коннектится, забирает все что было указано в select из БД и держит это в памяти, после манипуляций с данными, тоже один раз коннектится к БД и отдает все изменения. То есть по сути работает с локальной копией БД в памяти, а не непосредственно с постоянным коннектом к БД

Comment: _создаю объект DataTable_ ... _а потом это все отправить в датасет, чтобы сгенерировалась таблица._ не понимаю этого. У тебя таблицы уже созданы. Добавь их просто в коллекцию таблиц DataSet.Table.

Comment: Неее, в том то и проблема, что так не работает. По факту в физическую БД не отправляется

Comment: Что не работает? Конкретизируй вопрос. Что тебе нужно получить в DataSet в конечном итоге? _"По факту в физическую БД не отправляется"_ Что не отправляется?

Comment: В конечном счете, я хочу чтобы после добавления `DataTable` в массив `Tables` в `DataSet` эта новая таблица данных появилась в физической БД

Comment: То есть раньше этой таблицы не было, потом после манипуляций описанных выше она появилась